Janossy densities and the relation with density with respect to a Poisson point process
In the spatial point process literature, it is customary to specify a point process by assigning its density with respect to a Poisson point process.
For instance, an Hardcore point process $\mathbf X$ on a compact region $R$ can be defined by its density $f$ with respect to the unit-rate Poisson process on $R$ given by
$$
   f(\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}) \propto \beta^n \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq m} I[\|x_i - x_j\| > r].
$$
In this sense, $f(\cdot)$ is the unique function such that for all measurable function $h: \mathcal N \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ it holds true
$$
E[h(\mathbf X)] = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{e^{-|R|}}{n!} \int_{R^n} h(\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\})  f(\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}) dx_1 \cdots dx_n
$$
where $\mathcal N$ is the set of all finite point configurations of $R$.
When reading references more focused on the probabilistic aspects of point processes, these densities are rarely mentioned. However, the concept of Janossy density is used.
For instance, in [1], the authors introduce the $L_{R}$ sampling measure defined by
$$
\int_{\mathcal N} h(\alpha) L_R(d \alpha) = \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{m!} \int_{R^m} h(\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}) \lambda(dx_1) \cdots \lambda(dx_m)
$$
and define the Janossy density, $j_X(\cdot)$, of a point process on $R$ as a density with respect to $L_R$.
Here is my question: am I right in saying that when both the density with respect to the unit rate Poisson process and the Janossy density exist (and $L_R$ is such that $\lambda(\cdot)$ is the Lebesgue measure), then they are related by
$$
f(\cdot) = e^{-|R|} j_X(\cdot),
$$
or am I missing something?
[1] Georgii and Yoo. "Conditional Intensity and Gibbsianness of Determinantal Point" Processes, Journal of Statistical Physics

Yes, you are correct. There are some discussions about the definition of Janossy densities in Chapter 7.1 of "An Introduction to the Theory of Point Processes, Volume I: Elementary Theory and Methods, Second Edition" by Daley and Vere-Jones.
They define the Janossy densities $j_X(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ of a PP as the probability density of the $x_i$ with respect to the n-fold product of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ corresponding, up to the $e^{-|R|}$ factor, to a unit-rate Poisson PP. This is a different way of explaining the relationship between $f$ and $j_X$ you pointed out.
